# Appearing of Weird Cornered Cloud in Sky?

Tags: atmosphere

It was about 6'o Clock in the Evening. Suddenly I noticed A wierd Cloud in the middle of the sky.

[image]

[image]

Is there Natural Phenomenon responsible for creating such prefect clouds? & What it is?

or

Human activities like Climate Change?

or

Just a Coincidence ?

[image]

Comment: Are you by change talking about how there's a sharp line on the bottom of the white cloud?  I might well be able to help some on that.  Or if not, what stands out as weird about it to you?

Comment: Two other things that might help sort it out some is what location you were at when you took it, and what date (or approximate time of year) it was when you took it :-)

Comment: @JeopardyTempest In my life I've never witness such a cloud, its so rare to have such a straight edge... Is it an illusion?

Comment: The straight edge on the bottom?

Comment: (If you find the language a bit of a challenge in this question, and [online translators](https://translate.google.com) no help, perhaps we can find someone to help in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=earthscience.stackexchange.com)?  What language do you speak?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The left edge of the cloud is a real edge, irregular and fuzzy as expected. However, the lower sharp edge is just an illusion due to illumination. Just before sunrise or after sunset, the sun can illuminate the upper clouds but not the lower ones. If a cloud happen to be in the limit between illuminated clouds and shaded clouds, it will have its upper side illuminated and the lower one in the shade. That is what you are seeing, the lower edge is not the edge of the cloud, is just the limit of the illuminated part of it.

If you pay attention you can follow the contrast in illumination even outside of the cloud to the left. Where the illuminated air above the line have a glow not visible in the part under the illuminated part.

Comment: Sun is on Right side, Its sunset & west is on left. Wait for Edit

Comment: Check the question For the Directions as marked

Comment: If it is sunset and you are on planet Earth, the sun must be on the West. Therefore the Sun must be in the left side of the picture. Which, given the tilt of the lower edge it would be consistent with my interpretation.

Comment: Yes, That's the answer I wanted Before. It solved my confusion. Thanks...

Answer (score 3):

First of all, there is no "non-natural" way to create clouds, unless you count vapor trails from jet aircraft.

Next, you seem to be confusing scattered light from one cloud layer with the local shape of another cloud layer.  The human mind is highly skilled, so to speak, at creating shapes and figures where they don't really exist.  Thus the observation that clouds look like dragons, or fish, or cathedrals.    You've simply photographed a shape that attracted you.

Comment: Well, there's https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BIpeNs5OWbo and even https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/19241/why-does-condensation-form-on-the-wing-especially-during-take-off-and-landing as slight alternatives to creating clouds.  That said I think your analysis is generally on target :-)

Comment: Though to me at least, your answer seems to sort of come off a little harsh in it's tone. Maybe others see it differently, but phrases like "first of all", "confusing", and "simply" seem spots where you could apply friendlier wording :-)  And maybe it's could be see as a tad terse/abrupt. I'm definitely a fan in trying to be warm and to convey things in an approachable and understanding way to questioners (many just may not consider such things or be of varying ages or backgrounds... heck, who knows, could even be from a person who lives in a remote desert and almost never sees clouds!)

Comment: Really not intending such thoughts to be anything to stress you or to take personally, and I may be totally off base... just hoping to provide independent input as to how someone might interpret things, and encourage us all.  I, as many, can certainly still use some work to improve my language and tone in many situations :-) :-) :-)

Comment: but look at the bottom Edge of the Cloud, Its edge is so straight.

Comment: Yes I strongly Agree with that, its called Pareidolia. But its not really involved in that?